# sublime text 2 C++ run error on windows

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I am using Windows 7 x32 and have already installed, sublime text 2, MinGW, also set PATH for minGW in system variables, but it still does not work. 
I try to build it get [Finished in 0.8s] and then I try run, get this:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ 'C:\\Users\\air\\Desktop\\test.cpp' -o 'C:\\Users\\air\\Desktop/cc' && 'C:\\Users\\air\\Desktop/test'"]]
[dir:  C:\Users\air\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib;D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin;D:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin;D:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin]
[Finished]
```

It seems that because linux uses "/", but windows uses "\" in the file path. I try to change the  "C++.sublime-build", but failed. I really don't know how to fix it, Can anybody help me?

Comment: Windows supports both, slash and backslash in almost all cases. You can even mix and match them as you desire (which is obviously not recommended). Only when calling an executable in a command prompt, you're forced to use backslashes for the executable program to be run. I'd say the issue here is the escaping, but I don't know why that's done. As for cross platform stuff (e.g. makefiles), the use of `/` is recommended.

Comment: I'm new here, I'm so glad that you can answer my question. Thank you. Maybe I should not flip flop. I can still use codeblocks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the answer came simple as 42: since bash needs to be run in `cmd` command, it must be in the `path` variable. In my case, bash was contained in MSYS (which can be installed optionally with MinGW), I added `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` to path, restarted Sublime Text and now run command is working.